# Route53 pointing nameservers to Bluehost not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, shared-hosting, amazon-route53, nameservers

I purchased my domain name on Route53 and tried to point the nameserver to Bluehost's (where my Wordpress site is located). I set the nameserver settings in Route53 but it has been 2 days and it doesn't seem like anything has propagated - I get no response via `dig` or `ping` as well.

I've been instructed that the nameservers for Bluehost are:

`ns1.bluehost.com`
`ns2.bluehost.com`

Here is what my Route53 settings look like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't the nameserver settings.

If you registered your domain through Amazon, click "Registered Domains" on the left side of the page, and click "Add or edit name servers" in the details page for the appropriate domain.

If you registered your domain somewhere else, you'll need to change the nameservers there.